# saving data on textview of listview item and in database using dialog

Tags: android, listview

Here I m trying to save and store data in to `SQLite` database by poping up the dialog  onLong click on the `listview` item (Each `listview` items contains `textView` and`toggle` button, similar 8 items generated by adapter).

Dialog contains `edittext` field, on entering the data and clicking on OK Button should create database and same should be the text of `textview` of that item of `listview` only.

•   I m facing problem in changing the data of the `textView` of `listview` item and also in setting up database. Any suggestion will be of great help Thank you...

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ListAdapter.customButtonListener {
    String ipaddress, ipaddress1;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    EditText ed1,ed2;
    private ListView listView;
    public static final String MY_PREFERENCES = "MyPreferences";
    SharedPreferences myPreferences;
    ListAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> dataItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ProgressDialog waitDialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert;
    String noteID;
    TextView child;
    NoteHelper helper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String[] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listdata);
        List<String> dataTemp = Arrays.asList(dataArray);
        dataItems.addAll(dataTemp);
        ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        helper=new NoteHelper(this);
        child=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
        //alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, dataItems);
        adapter.setCustomButtonListner(MainActivity.this);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int i, long l) {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            dialog.show();
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.prompts);
            dialog.setTitle("Update!!!");
            final EditText userinput=(EditText)dialog.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

            Button Update = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
            Button Cancel=(Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonCANCEL);

            Update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (userinput.getText() != null) {
                        String text=userinput.getText().toString();
                        //child.setText(userinput.getText().toString());
                        myPreferences = getSharedPreferences (MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPreferences.edit ();
                        editor.putString(MY_PREFERENCES,text);
                        editor.commit ();

                        myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);

                        String strUsername = myPreferences.getString(MY_PREFERENCES,text);
                        // child.setText(strUsername);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+userinput.getText()+"uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

            Cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
            return true;

        }
    });
}
```

ListAdapter.java

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    customButtonListener customListner;

    public interface customButtonListener {
        public void onButtonClickListner(int position,String value);
        public void onClickListner(int position, String temp);
    }

    public void setCustomButtonListner(customButtonListener listener) {
        this.customListner = listener;
    }

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> dataItem) {
        super(context, R.layout.row, dataItem);
        this.data = dataItem;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      final  ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childTextView);
            viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childButton);
            viewHolder.buttonoff = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.childButton1);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        final String temp = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.text.setText(temp);
        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (customListner != null) {
                    customListner.onButtonClickListner(position,temp);
                }
            }
        });
        viewHolder.buttonoff.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (customListner != null) {
                    customListner.onClickListner(position, temp);
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        Button button;
        Button buttonoff;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        >
    </ListView>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="IP ADDRESS"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/childTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/childButton" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/childButton"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="ON"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="61dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/childButton1"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:text="OFF"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/childButton"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

prompts.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
    <requestFocus/>
</EditText>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonOK"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="UPDATE"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/dialogButtonCANCEL"
    android:layout_width="105dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text=" CANCEL "
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextDialogUserInput"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dialogButtonOK" />
```

MainActivity.java

below is the code of onClickListener of the button in item of listView

```
@Override
public void onClickListner(int position, String temp,View view) {
    int position1 = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString());

    final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(dialog1.getWindow().getAttributes());
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    dialog1.show();
    dialog1.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
    dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.prompts);
    dialog1.setTitle("Update!!!");
    final EditText userinput=(EditText)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

    Button Update = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
    Button Cancel=(Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonCANCEL);

    Update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            String text=userinput.getText().toString();
            if(text!=null) {
                // If you want to find the textView sibling of the button you clicked and change its text
                //Null pointer exception occured
                ((TextView) ((View) v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.childTextView)).setText(text);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: _I m facing problem in changing the data of the textView of listview item and also in setting up database_. What kind of problem and how do you want to change data of listview?

Answer (score 0):

Setup the onClick method in your activity and hook it in the xml. Something like this

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/childButton1"
     android:layout_width="55dp"
     android:layout_height="55dp"
     android:text="OFF"
     android:onclick="onChildButton1"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/childButton"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Set a tag to this button in the listView adapter implementation

```
    holder.childButton1.setTag(position);
```

You can setup any information related to this row as a tag that you might require to perform the action on click.

Implement the method in your activity which has the listView

```
 public void onChildButton1(View view) {
       // Do your Dialog action here
       // If you want to figure out the position of the item of button just do this
      int position = Integer.parseInt(view.getTag().toString())

      // If you want to find the textView sibling of the button you clicked and change its text
      ((TextView)((View) view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.text_view_id)).setText("Your string");

 }
```

**EDIT**

You need to get the TextView of the list item not the dialog prompt

The function should look like this.

```
public void onChildButton1 (final View childButton1) {
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(dialog1.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
dialog1.show();
dialog1.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
dialog1.setContentView(R.layout.prompts);
dialog1.setTitle("Update!!!");
final EditText userinput=(EditText)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

Button Update = (Button) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
Button Cancel=(Button)dialog1.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonCANCEL);

Update.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            //int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
            String text=userinput.getText().toString();
        if(text!=null) {
            // If you want to find the textView sibling of the button you clicked and change its text

            //Null pointer exception resolved
            ((TextView) ((View) childButton1.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.childTextView)).setText(text);


        }
    }
});
}
```

Comment: sir your code is works fine,but when I try to extract the data entered in edittext of the dialog then "null pointer exception "occurs